# Maximizing the area of a cyclic trapezoid whose long base is the circumdiameter. Non-trigonometric solution?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

> A half circle with a radius of R encompasses an isosceles trapezoid such that the large base of the trapezoid is the diameter of the circle encompassing it.
>
> In terms of R, what is the length of the smaller base of all the possible trapezoids as described, whose area is maximal?

After some attempts at the problem, I managed to solve it using unit circle trigonometry, but I am curious if there are purely geometric solutions for this (which is what I was trying to find when I first attempted the problem).

Here is my solution:

Let $x$ be $\measuredangle AOD$
Let $h$ be the height of the trapezoid
Assume $0 < x < 90^\circ$

$$h = AO\sin x = R\sin x$$
$$AB = 2AO\cos x = 2R\cos x$$

Trapezoid area formula: $$\frac{AB + DC}{2} \cdot h $$
$$\downarrow$$
$$S_{(x)} = \frac{2R\cos x  + 2R}{2} \cdot R\sin x$$

From here, we find our function's derivative, get the $x$ for which there is a maxima, and plug it into our definition of AB to get it in terms of R, which would be AB = R.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: Yes, there is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any trigonometry here.

**Ellegant approach:** Try to think outside of the box! Ask yourself a more general question:

> Of all quadrilaterals $ABCD$ inscribed in a semicricle with diameter AB, which one has the maximum area?

[image]

We'll prove that for optimal quadrilateral:

$$BC=CD=DA=R\tag{1}$$

Suppose that (1) is not true. In other words, suppose that the optimal quadrilateral $ABCD$ looks like in the picture above and $AD\neq CD$. Find point $D'$ on arc AC such that $AD'=CD'$.

Note that triangle $\triangle ACD'$ has bigger area than $\triangle ACD$ because $h_{D'}>h_{D}$. So obviously:

$$P_{ABCD}=P_{ABC}+P_{ACD}<P_{ABC}+P_{ACD'}<P_{ABCD'}$$

So quadrialteral $ABCD$ has smaller area compared to $ABCD'$ and cannot be optimal. In other words, if (1) is not true, we can always find a quadrilateral with a bigger area. Consequentially, the quadrialteral with the biggest area must have sides $BC$, $CD$ and $DA$ of equal lengths which is possible only if (1) is true.

And such quadrialteral is also a trapezoid. Any other quadrilateral, being it a trapezoid or not must have a smaller area.

**No so ellegant approach, but still without trigonometry**:

Denote the height of the trapezod with $h$ and the length of the smaller base with $b$:

You have to maximize the following expression:

$$A=\frac{(2R+b)h}2$$

...or:

$$B=A^2=\left(R+\frac b2\right)^2h^2\tag{1}$$

...with the following constraint:

$$h^2=R^2-\left(\frac b2\right)^2\tag{2}$$

Replace (2) into (1) and you get:

$$B=\left(R+\frac b2\right)^2\left(R^2-\left(\frac b2\right)^2\right)$$

$$B=\left(R+\frac b2\right)^3\left(R-\frac b2\right)$$

For simplicity, introduce expression $c=R+\frac b2$:

$$B(c)=c^3(2R-c)$$

$$B'(c)=3c^2(2R-c)-c^3=0\implies c=\frac{3R}2\implies b=R$$

Comment: Marvelous answer. Thank you.